# How to check if google chrome is running

Tags: c#, process

I can close Google chrome via C# as follows:

```
Process[] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (Process p in chromeInstances)
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

but I do not know of a way to check if Google Chrome is running.

I would like to know way check that if google chrome is running or not first, thus will close Google chrome via C#.

Comment: What do you mean by *google chrome has been turned on* ?

Answer (score 6):

simply check the array you got

```
    Process[] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
    if (chromeInstances.Length > 0)
    {
        //then chrome is up
    }
    else
    {
        //not working now
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to practice with dealing with the Chrome instances via the `Process` object you can do code snippets with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net). Once you have this downloaded you can change your Language drop down to `C# Program` and paste this code in.  Take your time and play here and try things before posting another question. I see that you kind of asked a question before, got a semi answer, took that semi answer then created a new question off of it that is still not 100% clear what you are looking for.  StackOverflow is not here to do every step for you, make attempts first. If you are still stuck post YOUR code with a proper question to get help.

```
void Main()
{
    var chromeProcess = new ChromeProcess();
    Console.WriteLine(chromeProcess.AnyInstancesRunning());
    Console.WriteLine(chromeProcess.NumberOfInstancesRunning());
    chromeProcess.ChromeInstanceIds().Dump("Chrome Instance Ids");

    chromeProcess.KillChromeInstance(2816);

    //open and close a few chrome windows
    chromeProcess.RefreshInstances();
    Console.WriteLine(chromeProcess.AnyInstancesRunning());
    Console.WriteLine(chromeProcess.NumberOfInstancesRunning());
    chromeProcess.ChromeInstanceIds().Dump("Chrome Instance Ids");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class ChromeProcess
{
    private const string ImageName = "chrome";
    private IEnumerable<Process> _Instances;

    public ChromeProcess()
    {
        _Instances = Process.GetProcessesByName(ImageName);
    }

    public bool AnyInstancesRunning()
    {
        return _Instances.Any();
    }

    public int NumberOfInstancesRunning()
    {
        return _Instances.Count();
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> ChromeInstanceIds()
    {
        return _Instances.Select(i => i.Id).ToArray();
    }

    public void KillChromeInstance(int id)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessById(id);
        if(process.ProcessName != ImageName)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not a chrome instance.");
        }
        process.Kill();
    }

    public void RefreshInstances()
    {
        _Instances = Process.GetProcessesByName(ImageName);
    }
}
```